# Why do Beamer action specifications for TikZ nodes not behave like \uncover?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays

**NB.** I have completely rewritten this question to hopefully clarify things.

## Executive Summary

When creating TikZ diagrams in Beamer, one can add overlay specifications to paths and nodes, as in `\node<+-> {X};`.  Surprisingly, these overlay specifications behave differently than do pure Beamer overlay specifications!  Instead of behaving like `\uncover<+->{\node {X};}` (as one would expect from pure Beamer `\item`s), it behaves like `\only<+->{\node {X};}`.

Why is this, and is it possible to have `\node` treat its specification like pure Beamer?  See the end of this post for detailed questions.

## Background

### Action Specifications in "Pure" Beamer

In the Beamer manual, the description of the `actionenv` environment states:

> An `⟨overlay specification⟩` without an action is promoted to `uncover@⟨overlay specification⟩`.

Here's an example using `itemize` lists that shows the promotion of `+-` to `uncover@+-`--when the rendering of covered material is set to `invisible` (default) and `transparent`, respectively--and compares its behavior to that of `only@+-`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Action Specifications with \texttt{\textbackslash item}}
  \begin{columns}
  \column{0.35\textwidth}
    Below uses spec \texttt{<+->}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item<+-> X
    \item<+-> Y
    \item<+-> Z
    \end{itemize}
    Above uses spec \texttt{<+->}

    \vspace{\baselineskip}

    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
    Below uses spec \texttt{<+->}
    with \texttt{transparent}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item<+-> X
    \item<+-> Y
    \item<+-> Z
    \end{itemize}
    Above uses spec \texttt{<+->}
    with \texttt{transparent}

  \column{0.45\textwidth}
    Below uses spec \texttt{<only@+->}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item<only@+-> X
    \item<only@+-> Y
    \item<only@+-> Z
    \end{itemize}
    Above uses spec \texttt{<only@+->}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Action Specifications for TikZ `\node`s

However, this same behavior is *not* exhibited by overlay specifications given to TikZ `\path`s and `\node`s:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Action Specifications with \texttt{\textbackslash node}}
  \begin{columns}
  \column{0.35\textwidth}
    Below uses spec \texttt{<+->}\\
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node<+-> at (0, 0)   {X};
      \node<+-> at (0,-0.5) {Y};
      \node<+-> at (0,-1)   {Z};
    \end{tikzpicture}\\
    Above uses spec \texttt{<+->}

    \vspace{\baselineskip}

    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
    Below uses spec \texttt{<+->}
    with \texttt{transparent}\\
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node<+-> at (0, 0)   {X};
      \node<+-> at (0,-0.5) {Y};
      \node<+-> at (0,-1)   {Z};
    \end{tikzpicture}\\
    Above uses spec \texttt{<+->}
    with \texttt{transparent}

  \column{0.55\textwidth}
    Below uses spec \texttt{<only@+->}\\
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node<only@+-> at (0, 0)   {X};
      \node<only@+-> at (0,-0.5) {Y};
      \node<only@+-> at (0,-1)   {Z};
    \end{tikzpicture}\\
    Above uses spec \texttt{<only@+->}

    \vspace{\baselineskip}

    Below uses spec \texttt{<uncover@+->}\\
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node<uncover@+-> at (0, 0)   {X};
      \node<uncover@+-> at (0,-0.5) {Y};
      \node<uncover@+-> at (0,-1)   {Z};
    \end{tikzpicture}\\
    Above uses spec \texttt{<uncover@+->}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Unlike when it is used with `\item`s, the action specification `<+->` (with or without setting `transparent`) does not allocate space for the `\node`s.  In other words, the nodes are used in a `\only` manner, not in the `\uncover` manner that I expected.  Moreover, adding an explicit `only@` or `uncover@` causes those `\node`s to appear on all slides, as if they were given no action specification at all!

## Questions

- Is there a way to recover full action specifications for paths and nodes?  Yes, using `\uncover<+>{\node at (0,0) {X};}` etc. is a reasonable workaround, but is there another way to give the action specification to `\node` directly?
- If not, where is the code for action-specification-aware `\node`s within the Beamer source?
   I'd like to try my hand at modifying the code to fix this inconsistency, but I haven't
   been able to locate the relevant macros.

Comment: I don't see any problem if I choose to use `<+->` spec. The `<+>` is more or less *Show only on this slide and remove it on the next one*.

Comment: @percusse I think my original question was unclear.  Even with `<+->`, there is still a difference: `\item<+->` leaves space for all `\item`s even on slides where they are invisible, but `\node<+->` doesn't.  I've re-written my question to hopefully clarify.

Answer (score 2):

The notation `<+>` means *replace* the last instance, what you want is `<+->` which means *add* step by step:

### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Ti\textit{k}Z}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node<+-> at (0,0) {X};
    \node<+-> at (1,0) {Y};
    \node<+-> at (2,0) {Z};

    \draw (current bounding box.south west)
          rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  This doesn't quite do what I want, though:  `\item<+->` leaves space for the `\item` even on slides where it is invisible, but `\node<+->` does not.  I have re-written my question to hopefully clarify.